# Accessing all list templates

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, csom, list-template

I'm not able to access all the default list templates. I'm getting the error as invalid list template

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://chnsharepoint:38940/listlibrary"))
            {


                    // The SharePoint web at the URL.
                    Web web = context.Web;
                    ListCreationInformation Info = new ListCreationInformation();
                    Info.Title = "117NoCodePublic";
                    Info.TemplateType = 117;
                    List list = web.Lists.Add(Info);
                    list.Update();
                    context.Load(web);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

```
// Get the list template by name
ListTemplate listTemplate = web.ListTemplates.GetByName("templateName");     
ctx.Load(listTemplate);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();     
ListCreationInformation creationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
creationInfo.Title = "My List";
creationInfo.Description = "Description";     
// Set a value that specifies the feature identifier of the feature 
// that contains the list schema for the new list.
creationInfo.TemplateFeatureId = listTemplate.FeatureId;     
// Set a value that specifies the list server template of the new list
creationInfo.TemplateType = listTemplate.ListTemplateTypeKind;     
web.Lists.Add(creationInfo);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;  
namespace ClassLibrary1   
    {  
       class Program   
        {  
            static void Main(string[] args)   
            {  
                //ClientContext - Get the context for the SharePoint Site    
                ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://chnsharepoint:38940/listlibrary");  
                //Get the SharePoint web    
                Web web = clientContext.Web;  
                ListTemplateCollection templateCollection = web.ListTemplates;  
                clientContext.Load(templateCollection);  
                //Execute the query to the server    
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  
                // Loop through all the list templates    
                foreach(ListTemplate template in templateCollection)   
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine("Template Name: " + template.Name);  
                }  
                    Console.ReadLine();  
                }  
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Did this answer your question Vishal? If it did then please accept the answer and vote for it. Thanks